# assign value to selected input box in a row using Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

row add using angular code. Input box model name is "code". when click this input box a model open and when any row select using angularjs then there is a problem when I assign value using $scope.code it will assign to all input box in but I want to assign that value by which ng-click performed.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
    <tr style="font-weight: bold">
        <td style="width:35%">Code</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td>
            <!-- editable username (text with validation) -->
            <span ng-show="editDel">
            @{{ user.name || 'empty' }}
            </span>
            @{{code}}
            <input type="text" name="" ng-model="code" ng-show="saveCancel" ng-click="getCode()">
        </td>

        <td style="white-space: nowrap">
            <!-- form -->
            <form ng-show="saveCancel" class="form-buttons form-inline">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            save
            </button>
            <button type="button" ng-click="isCancel()" class="btn btn-default">
            cancel
            </button>
            </form>
            <div class="buttons" ng-show="editDel">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editUser($index)">edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeUser($index)">del</button>
            </div>  
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$scope.users = []; 
$scope.saveCancel = false;
$scope.editDel = true;

$scope.saveUser = function(data, id) {
    //$scope.user not updated yet
    angular.extend(data, {id: id});
    return $http.post('/saveUser', data);
};

// remove user
$scope.removeUser = function(index) {
    $scope.users.splice(index, 1);
};

// add user add row
$scope.addUser = function() {
    $scope.inserted = {
      id: $scope.users.length+1,
      name: '',
      status: null,
      group: null 
    };
    // $scope.taxNamePopup();
    $scope.users.push($scope.inserted);
};

$scope.getCode = function(){
    // alert(input_id);
    this.code = 'nameValue';//**this assin value to selected box**
    // jQuery("#tax_modal").modal("hide");
    var request = $http({
        method: "get",
        url: base_url+"/load-tax",
        data: {
        },
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        jQuery("#tax_list").modal("show");
        $scope.tax_data1 = response;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });
}

$scope.getSelected = function(id,code,desc,rate){
     alert(code);
     this.code = code;//**but i want to assign value to selected input box from here**
     jQuery("#tax_list").modal("hide");
}

$scope.safeApply(function() {
  $scope.editUser = function($id){
    this.saveCancel = true;
    this.editDel = false;
  }
});

$scope.isCancel = function(){
    this.saveCancel = false;
    this.editDel = true;
}
```

Comment: Is code a scope variable or a property of the user object?

Answer (score 0):

> it is because `ng-model` is `code`for every `input`.

Change it with following code example

```
<input type="text" name="" ng-model="code_$index" ng-show="saveCancel" ng-click="getCode($index)">
```

Now above code will change the `ng-model`  unique for each input field and retrieve the value in getCode on the basis of index.

Answer (score 0):

the model should be different for each ng-repeat item

#### EDIT change from getCode(user.code) to getCode(user)

```
<input type="text" name="" ng-model="user.code" ng-show="saveCancel" ng-click="getCode(user)">
```

use the param how ever you want ;)

```
$scope.getCode = function(user){
      angular.forEach($scope.users, function (value, key) {
          if (value.id == user.id) {
                  $scope.users[key]=user;
          }
     });
}
```

Comment: what should be used inside the function to assign value to selected input box
$scope.getCode = function(code){
    $scope.user.code = "value";
}

Comment: if you want to assign  value to it use pass in user to `getcode(user)` then in loop through the users get the user with the same id or anything unique and then assign

Comment: dear

I am still unable to assign value to 'ng-model="user.code"' (which clicked).